# while loop not terminating on changing test condition

Tags: python, input, while-loop

Case 1 terminates on the 1st loop which makes sense, however case 2 does not, even after entering an input of 5? Why Not?
What i have done to troubleshoot: Initially I suspected it might have to do with a different "x" variable being created on each loop, maybe? But that didn't seem to make sense as we'd never be able to update a count if a different variable was created each iteration.
Scope/namespace? Shouldn't be different from case 1, as far as i can tell
different reference? I printed out the id()s for both cases, the newly assigned "x" variable is stored at different locations. Thus this seems irrelevant to the problem.

Any help?

## case 1

```
x = 8
print('initial x', x, id(x))
while (x != 5):
    x = 5
    print('final_x', x, id(x))
```

## case 2

```
x = 8
print('initial x', x, id(x))
while (x != 5):
    x = input("Please enter the number 5: ")
    print('final_x', x, id(x))
```

Comment: `input()` in Python 3 returns a string -- `'5'`, not `5`.

Comment: Oops. So sorry. Didn't check for that. Facepalm. Thanks!!!

Comment: @l'L'l, you mean, `while int(x) != 5:`; `5` is already an int.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: yep, i woke up on the wrong side of the bed. :p